# Want to exit eclipse ee, but got an error

Tags: eclipse, server

As the title says, I want to exit Eclipse, but got a prompted window: `Problem occurred: org/eclipse/tm/terminal/view/ui/view/TerminalsView`
Could someone show me how to exit it? Thanks!